# ¿Cual es la forma mas correcta de hacer una actualización a una base de datos mongodb en mlab usando jsp?

Tags: html, jsp, mongodb, nosql

Buenas!

Resulta que tengo por hacer una actualización en mi base de datos en mlab de mongodb. Pero me encuentro con el problema que no he podido que mis datos se actualicen. Es decir, los datos llegan correctamente tanto de los request parameter (los nuevos) y los que saco de la base de datos (datos a reemplazar). He hecho este tipo de actualización varias veces y funciona! Pero honestamente no he podido encontrar el error.

Es largo, pero solo en variables.

```
<%@page import="static com.mongodb.client.model.Updates.*"%>
<%@page import="static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="com.mongodb.client.FindIterable"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="com.mongodb.client.model.Filters"%>
<%@page import="com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection"%>
<%@page import="org.bson.Document"%>
<%@page import="com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase"%>
<%@page import="com.mongodb.MongoClient"%>
<%@page import="com.mongodb.MongoClientURI"%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Confirmación de Actualización</title>
        <script>

        </script>
        </head>
    <body>
       <ul class="adeo">
            <li class="ameo"><img src="../img/logo.jpg" alt=""/></li>            
            <li class="ameo"><a class="active" href="../index.html">Inicio</a></li>
            <li class="ameo"><a href="IngresarpacientesFRM.html">Ingresar Paciente</a></li>
            <li class="ameo"><a href="FiltrarporCedFRM.html">Buscar Pacientes</a></li>
            <li class="ameo"><a href="FiltroporCedActBorFRM.html">Actualizar o Borrar Estancias y Pacientes</a></li>
            <li class="ameo"><a href="VertodoFRM.html">Ver todas las Estancias</a></li>
        </ul>  
    <div id="printableArea" style="margin-left:25%;padding:1px 16px;height:1000px;">
        <%

            String cedulamadrex = request.getParameter("txtcedmadre");
            String cedulapadrex = request.getParameter("txtcedpadre");
            String nombremadrex = request.getParameter("txtnmmadre");
            String nombrepadrex = request.getParameter("txtnmpadre");
            String novedadmx = request.getParameter("rbtnvom");
            String novedadpx = request.getParameter("rbtnvam");
            String cedulaabumax = request.getParameter("txtcedabuma");
            String cedulaabuemax = request.getParameter("txtcedabuema");
            String nombreabumax = request.getParameter("txtnmabuma");
            String nombreabuemax = request.getParameter("txtnmabuema");
            String novedadabumax = request.getParameter ("rbtnvim");
            String novedadabuemax = request.getParameter ("rbtnvum");
            String cedulaabupax = request.getParameter("txtcedabupa");
            String cedulaabuepax = request.getParameter("txtcedabuepa");
            String nombreabupax = request.getParameter("txtnmabupa");
            String nombreabuepax = request.getParameter("txtnmabuepa");
            String novedadabupax = request.getParameter ("rbtnvem");
            String novedadabuepax = request.getParameter ("rbtnvxm");
            String observacionx = request.getParameter("txtaobservacion");
            String serviciox = request.getParameter("slcservicio");
            String estanciax = request.getParameter("estancia");




            MongoClientURI mongoURI =new MongoClientURI(""
                    + "mongodb://prainformatica:Clinica2016@ds035826.mlab.com:35826/cp_vneonatos");
            MongoClient conexion = new MongoClient(mongoURI);

            MongoDatabase db = conexion.getDatabase("cp_vneonatos");

            MongoCollection<Document> coleccion = db.getCollection("Datosfamiliar");

            List<Document> docs = coleccion.find(new Document("cedulamadre",cedulamadrex)).into(new ArrayList<Document>());

            String cedulamadre = "";
            String cedulapadre = "";
            String nombremadre = "";
            String nombrepadre = "";
            String novedadm = "";
            String novedadp = "";
            String cedulaabuma = "";
            String cedulaabuema = "";
            String nombreabuma = "";
            String nombreabuema = "";
            String novedadabuma= "";
            String novedadabuema = "";
            String cedulaabupa = "";
            String cedulaabuepa = "";
            String nombreabupa = "";
            String nombreabuepa = "";
            String novedadabupa = "";
            String novedadabuepa = "";
            String observacion = "";
            String servicio = "";
            String estancia = "";

            for(int s = 0; s<docs.size();s++){

                Document neonatos = (Document)docs.get(s);

             cedulamadre = neonatos.getString("cedulamadre");
             cedulapadre = neonatos.getString("cedulapadre");
             nombremadre = neonatos.getString("nombremadre");
             nombrepadre = neonatos.getString("nombrepadre");
             novedadm = neonatos.getString("novedadm");
             novedadp = neonatos.getString("novedadp");
             cedulaabuma = neonatos.getString("cedulaabuma");
             cedulaabuema = neonatos.getString("cedulaabuema");
             nombreabuma = neonatos.getString("nombreabuma");
             nombreabuema = neonatos.getString("nombreabuema");
             novedadabuma = neonatos.getString("novedadabuma");
             novedadabuema = neonatos.getString("novedadabuema");
             cedulaabupa = neonatos.getString("cedulaabupa");
             cedulaabuepa = neonatos.getString("cedulaabuepa");
             nombreabupa = neonatos.getString("nombreabupa");
             nombreabuepa = neonatos.getString("nombreabuepa");
             novedadabupa = neonatos.getString("novedadabupa");
             novedadabuepa = neonatos.getString("novedadabuepa");
             observacion = neonatos.getString("observacion");
             servicio = neonatos.getString("servicio");
             estancia = neonatos.getString("estancia");

            }

            out.print("");


            coleccion.updateMany(and(eq("cedulamadre",cedulamadre),
                                    eq("cedulapadre",cedulapadre),
                                    eq("cedulaabuma",cedulaabuma),
                                    eq("cedulabuema",cedulaabuema),
                                    eq("cedulaabupa",cedulaabupa),
                                    eq("cedulaabuepa",cedulaabuepa),
                                    eq("nombremadre",nombremadre),
                                    eq("nombrepadre",nombrepadre),
                                    eq("nombreabuma",nombreabuma),
                                    eq("nombreabuema",nombreabuema),
                                    eq("nombreabupa",nombreabupa),
                                    eq("nombreabuepa",nombreabuepa),
                                    eq("novedadm",novedadm),
                                    eq("novedadp",novedadp),
                                    eq("novedadabuma",novedadabuma),
                                    eq("novedadabuema",novedadabuema),
                                    eq("novedadabupa",novedadabupa),
                                    eq("novedadabuepa",novedadabuepa),
                                    eq("observacion",observacion),
                                    eq("estancia",estancia),
                                    eq("servicio",servicio)),

                                and(set("cedulamadre",cedulamadrex),
                                    set("cedulapadre",cedulapadrex),
                                    set("cedulaabuma",cedulaabumax),
                                    set("cedulabuema",cedulaabuemax),
                                    set("cedulaabupa",cedulaabupax),
                                    set("cedulaabuepa",cedulaabuepax),
                                    set("nombremadre",nombremadrex),
                                    set("nombrepadre",nombrepadrex),
                                    set("nombreabuma",nombreabumax),
                                    set("nombreabuema",nombreabuemax),
                                    set("nombreabupa",nombreabupax),
                                    set("nombreabuepa",nombreabuepax),
                                    set("novedadm",novedadmx),
                                    set("novedadp",novedadpx),
                                    set("novedadabuma",novedadabumax),
                                    set("novedadabuema",novedadabuemax),
                                    set("novedadabupa",novedadabupax),
                                    set("novedadabuepa",novedadabuepax),
                                    set("observacion",observacionx),
                                    set("estancia",estanciax),
                                    set("servicio",serviciox)));





           out.print("<center>SE HAN ACTUALIZADO LOS DATOS CON EXITO</center>");

            out.print(cedulamadre
                    +"<br>"+cedulapadre
                    +"<br>"+cedulaabuma
                    +"<br>"+cedulaabuema
                    +"<br>"+cedulaabupa
                    +"<br>"+cedulaabuepa
                    +"<br>"+nombremadre
                    +"<br>"+nombrepadre
                    +"<br>"+nombreabuepa
                    +"<br>"+nombreabupa
                    +"<br>"+nombreabuema
                    +"<br>"+nombreabuma
                    +"<br>"+observacion
                    +"<br>"+estancia
                    +"<br>"+servicio
                    +"<br>"+novedadm
                    +"<br>"+novedadp
                    +"<br>"+novedadabuema
                    +"<br>"+novedadabuma
                    +"<br>"+novedadabupa
                    +"<br>"+novedadabuepa);

            out.print("<br>"
                    + "<br>"
                    + "<br>"
                    + "<br>"
                    + "<br>"
                    + "<br>");
            out.print(cedulamadrex
                    +"<br>"+cedulapadrex
                    +"<br>"+cedulaabumax
                    +"<br>"+cedulaabuemax+
                    "<br>"+cedulaabupax
                    +"<br>"+cedulaabuepax
                    +"<br>"+nombremadrex
                    +"<br>"+nombrepadrex
                    +"<br>"+nombreabuepax
                    +"<br>"+nombreabupax
                    +"<br>"+nombreabuemax
                    +"<br>"+nombreabumax
                    +"<br>"+observacionx
                    +"<br>"+estanciax
                    +"<br>"+serviciox                    
                    +"<br> madrex "+novedadmx
                    +"<br> padrex "+novedadpx
                    +"<br> abumax "+novedadabumax
                    +"<br> abuemax "+novedadabuemax
                    +"<br> abupax "+novedadabupax
                    +"<br> abuepax "+novedadabuepax);
        %>

    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```